# Jquery add class on hover and active

Tags: jquery

With this code my nav items flicks on click (to the default color) for a short sec.

I want to add a specific color on hover and when li.active

any suggestions? thanks guys!

```js
jQuery('.custom-nav-ul a').each(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).attr('href') === "/landbrug/") {
                    jQuery(this).addClass('landbrug');
                    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('landbrug-active');
                    }
                    
                }
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery? Why not css i.e. .custom-nav-ul a:hover{//style} .custom-nav-ul a.active {//style}

Comment: My navigation is dynamic and the links got diff. colors dependent on the names. But I could make the one's I need static, thanks you :)  got me thinking.

Answer (score 0):

True.  Using css would be better. 
    .custom-nav-ul a:hover{//landbrug style content} 
    .custom-nav-ul a.active {//landbrug-active style content}